# How to child-proof a floor vent?

Tags: vent, child-safety

Our upstairs playroom has a floor vent leading to the furnace that children like to throw toys down. Is there any kind of vent cover that can be substituted that is less likely to  result in this activity?

Comment: Hi Village, Interesting question. Presumably the floor vent has a grille of some sort. Is it the case that the children are lifting the grille off the floor? Or are they simply pushing small things through the openings of the grille? Lastly is it possible that you could fasten down the grille somehow?

Comment: I understood your question to mean that your child is removing the cover, not just putting it through the cracks in the vent, is that accurate?

Comment: No, the cover with the grille is too difficult to remove. They put it through the cracks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It sounds as if the vent is completely open - hope that isn't the case. It could be dangerous.
Assuming you have some type of vent cover on it I would cut and attach a piece of wire or even cloth mesh over the top or just under the vent cover. The wire would probably work best under the vent cover. You could attach it to the cover itself or the ductwork.

[image]

Comment: There appears to be sharp edges and pokey things around the ends which would not be good around children and I can't up vote unless that is addressed

Comment: @Ack Yeah - if it's on top it should be the cloth. Under I'd do the wire. Thought it was clear but I'll edit.

Answer (score 3):

Extend it up higher and put a 90 or U bend with a grille on it.

Comment: My interpretation is that this is a vent built into the floor itself.  Extending "up higher" wont work unless you also redirect it to the interior of a wall orsome such.

Comment: @CarlWitthoft that may well be correct, but the OP did not say so I suggested a possibility...

Answer (score 2):

If this is truly in the floor itself (as I've seen in plenty of ancient houses here in New England), then moving it isn't an option.  I would second the suggestion to put in a grille. I would probably look for a piece of "perforated" steel, i.e. one with small holes closely spaced.  Pick holes smaller than their toys.  If they've graduated to crayons or pencils, then you will probably need some very fine grid, or a layer of screen over the grille plate.

Comment: Also keep in mind the size of their fingers, [example from my local newspaper](https://translate.google.com/translate?hl=nl&sl=nl&tl=en&u=omroepwest.nl%2Fnieuws%2F3368592%2FAlle-1100-bankjes-bij-tram-en-bushaltes-vervangen-na-ongelukken-met-kinderen)

Comment: @Pelle  ouch!  What kids will do..